# iPod touch notification center

Tags: ipod-touch, notifications

I exited out of a couple apps while I was in my notification center on my iPod touch. My settings still say that they will show up in the center, but they haven't been. I've gotten the message on my lock screen saying that I have a notification, but nothing in the notification center. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the specific app by turning Notification Center off, then back on.